# IBM notes java script library or package

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am creating some Java agents, in which I retrieve a HTML post and put it into a variable. In short I have this code:

```
      lotus.domino.Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
      String xml = "";
      Vector items = doc.getItems();
      for (int j=0; j<items.size(); j++)
        {
          Item item = (Item)items.elementAt(j);
          String fldName = item.getName();
          String fldValue = item.getValueString();
           if ( fldName.matches("(?i).*request_content.*") )
                {
                  sb.append( fldValue );
                  xml = sb.toString();
                  xml = xml.replace("&", "&amp;");

                }

                etc..
```

Now for multiple java agents this code is the same.. What would be best practise to do? Put this code in to a script library and java class or put it in to a java package?

And next how do I call a class from out a script library or custom made java package?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO: You should put a java class with this code in the java library and import it to agent (see pic.)
[image]